# Is there a method which is more logical to solve this question?

Tags: integration, random-variables, gaussian-integral

Question:

Using the normalization integration for a Gaussian random variables, find an analytic expression (closed-form solution) for the following integral
$I=\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}e^{-(ax^2+bx+c)}dx$

Solution:

$e^{-(ax^2+bx+c)}=e^{-a(x^2+\frac{b}{a}x+(\frac{b}{2a})^2+c-\frac{b^2}{4a^2})}=e^{-a(x+\frac{b}{2a})^2} \times {e^{\frac{b^2}{4a}-c}}$,so

$\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}e^{-(ax^2+bx+c)}dx=e^{\frac{b^2}{4a}-c}\times \sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{2a}} \int^{\infty}_{-\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{2a}}}e^{-\frac{(x+\frac{b}{2a})^2}{\frac{1}{a}}}dx=e^{(\frac{b^2}{4a}-c)} \times \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}}$

For these formula ,I think it is not logical for me,i mean,i think lots of people have to calculate by rote to solve or calculate this question,is there more logical way to solve this?i mean,by definition,and solve it,not  calculate it by rote.

Comment: I'm not sure how to interpret your question.  However, the way you show seems to be the only generally known way to solve it.  The steps are: (i) Recognize this kind of integral resembles a Gaussian PDF; (ii) complete the square to get a Gaussian PDF. The hint before the question indeed reminds you to think about integrating Gaussian PDFs.  There is no closed form anti-derivative for such $e^{-x^2}$  functions, so it seems there really is no other way to proceed.  [Other ways would likely be more complex and would secretly re-derive the Gaussian result, so it is easier to just use that result]

Comment: Of course the derivation requires $a>0$. If $a=0$ you integrate an exponential (which is easy), and if $a<0$ the total integral is $\infty$.